# How to check if an object has recordtypes specified or not?

Tags: apex, record-type, describesobject, schema

I want to find a way how can I check if a type of object, has any record types specified or not.

I tried, with the describe methods, by acquiring a List, according to the SObjectType, but this doesn't help me, because, even for those objects that I have'nt specified any record types, it returns at least a record type "Master"(which I guess should some internal default value specified by SFDC).

Thank you in advance guys!
Endrit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query the `RecordType` object to find out the record types that way.

```
List<RecordType> rts = [select Id 
                       from RecordType 
                       where SObjectType = :MyObject__c.SObjectType
                       ];
if (rts.size() > 0) {
    // MyObject__c has record types
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This way is easier to determine if an object has record types or not.